# python pandas groupby agg get lag1

Tags: python, pandas, aggregate

```
def lag1(x):
    return x[(len(x)-1)]
x=pd.Series([12,3,4,5,6])
lag1(x)
Out[65]: 6
dat.shape
Out[70]: (247619, 33)
d2=dat.groupby('PATID_CD').agg(lag1)
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-71-f514757a3da8>", line 1, in <module>
    d2=dat.groupby('PATID_CD').agg(lag1)

  File "D:\Users\shan xu\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py", line 4658, in aggregate
    return super(DataFrameGroupBy, self).aggregate(arg, *args, **kwargs)

  File "D:\Users\shan xu\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py", line 4109, in aggregate
    result = self._aggregate_generic(arg, *args, **kwargs)

  File "D:\Users\shan xu\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py", line 4133, in _aggregate_generic
    return self._aggregate_item_by_item(func, *args, **kwargs)

  File "D:\Users\shan xu\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py", line 4162, in _aggregate_item_by_item
    colg.aggregate(func, *args, **kwargs), data)

  File "D:\Users\shan xu\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py", line 3497, in aggregate
    result = self._aggregate_named(func_or_funcs, *args, **kwargs)

  File "D:\Users\shan xu\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py", line 3627, in _aggregate_named
    output = func(group, *args, **kwargs)

  File "<ipython-input-64-be977293b7b9>", line 2, in lag1
    return x[(len(x)-1)]

  File "D:\Users\shan xu\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 766, in __getitem__
    result = self.index.get_value(self, key)

  File "D:\Users\shan xu\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3103, in get_value
    tz=getattr(series.dtype, 'tz', None))

  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 106, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value

  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 114, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value

  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 162, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc

  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 958, in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item

  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 964, in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item
KeyError: 23
```

I don'tknow why my function not working, it gives me a keyerror which suggests the name does not exist. this is a little bit confusing. Am I doing the correct way, or there might be the other solution?

```
dat.groupby('PATID_CD').agg('mean')
Out[73]: 
           MONTH_LOOKBACK_NR      CCYYMM_CD    ...     ENG_SPOKEN  EVENT_FL
PATID_CD                                       ...                         
584                     12.0  201556.500000    ...            1.0       0.0
4277                    12.0  201556.500000    ...            1.0       0.0
```

I also tried:

```
dat.groupby('PATID_CD').agg(lambda x : x.iloc[-1,:])
```

This one is good, but I cannot put this function into a list that compute with the other functions:

```
def lag1(x):
    return x.iloc[-1,:]
d2=dat.groupby(dat['PATID_CD']).agg({'mean','max','min','std','skew', lambda x:len(x),kurtosis,lag1})
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-86-ac95a8297b5c>", line 1, in <module>

    d2=dat.groupby(dat['PATID_CD']).agg({'mean','max','min','std','skew', lambda x:len(x),kurtosis,lag1})

  File "D:\Users\shan xu\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py", line 4658, in aggregate
    return super(DataFrameGroupBy, self).aggregate(arg, *args, **kwargs)

  File "D:\Users\shan xu\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py", line 4089, in aggregate
    result, how = self._aggregate(arg, _level=_level, *args, **kwargs)

  File "D:\Users\shan xu\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\base.py", line 551, in _aggregate
    _axis=_axis), None

  File "D:\Users\shan xu\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\base.py", line 596, in _aggregate_multiple_funcs
    results.append(colg.aggregate(arg))

  File "D:\Users\shan xu\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py", line 3485, in aggregate
    (_level or 0) + 1)

  File "D:\Users\shan xu\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py", line 3558, in _aggregate_multiple_funcs
    results[name] = obj.aggregate(func)

  File "D:\Users\shan xu\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py", line 3497, in aggregate
    result = self._aggregate_named(func_or_funcs, *args, **kwargs)

  File "D:\Users\shan xu\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py", line 3627, in _aggregate_named
    output = func(group, *args, **kwargs)

  File "<ipython-input-85-6bbffa1ca952>", line 2, in lag1
    return x.iloc[-1,:]

  File "D:\Users\shan xu\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1472, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_tuple(key)

  File "D:\Users\shan xu\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 2013, in _getitem_tuple
    self._has_valid_tuple(tup)

  File "D:\Users\shan xu\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 220, in _has_valid_tuple
    raise IndexingError('Too many indexers')
```

IndexingError: Too many indexers
The same as this one:

```
x=pd.Series([12,3,4,5,6])
lag1(x)
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-85-6bbffa1ca952>", line 5, in <module>
    lag1(x)

  File "<ipython-input-85-6bbffa1ca952>", line 2, in lag1
    return x.iloc[-1,:]

  File "D:\Users\shan xu\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1472, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_tuple(key)

  File "D:\Users\shan xu\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 2013, in _getitem_tuple
    self._has_valid_tuple(tup)

  File "D:\Users\shan xu\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 220, in _has_valid_tuple
    raise IndexingError('Too many indexers')

IndexingError: Too many indexers
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't explained what you are trying to accomplish and it is not clear from your code. I don't have enough rep here to add this as a comment so consider:

1) Your first example is performed on a `Series` that implicitly uses a `RangeIndex`, so `x[(5-1)] == 6`. Your second example appears to be a DataFrame for which `PATID_CD` is the index. If `PATID_CD.dtype` is e.g. `object`, you will get a `KeyError` exception simply because you have passed the wrong argument type (an `int`) into a pandas indexing expression `DataFrame[label]` [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#basics).

2) If you simply want to extract the last row of a group, write your groupby call something like

```
dat.groupby('PATID_CD').apply(lambda x: x.iloc[-1, :])
```